# Testing a create / update API with images on Postman using node / postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, postman

I am trying to get a backend API working so that it upload photos along with other details and I can't figure out how to get Postman to accept the posting. The error seems to happen at the ".then((diveSpot) => {" line since I added the images field.

On my system I have the file type as "type: Sequelize.BLOB('long')" whereas it is "bytea[]" on Postgres as it doesn't handle the BLOB datatype. Is this the correct way to do this? does the [] part mean that I can add a number of photos? What do I need to put on my Sequelize model to specify I have an array of photos?

On the Postman create posting do I just enter the first four fields as per normal then use form data and the exact field name for the photos section and it will update like it is the fifth fields in my model.

```
exports.createDiveSpot = (req, res) => {
    // new dive spot to be added to db

    diveSpot.create({

        diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
        diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
        diveSpotTypeID: req.body.diveSpotTypeID,
        diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
        diveSpotPhotos: req.body.diveSpotPhotos
    })
        console.log(diveSpot)
        .then((diveSpot) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                statusCode: 200,
                success: true,
                message: "Success",
                diveSpot: diveSpot,
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
};
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What about this 'console.log' before the then() ?

Comment: Its just printing the word diveSpots for some reason. I have also been able to print random console.log text above it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the 'console.log', try to remove to this:

```
exports.createDiveSpot = (req, res) => {
// new dive spot to be added to db

diveSpot.create({

    diveLocation: req.body.diveLocation,
    diveRegionID: req.body.diveRegionID,
    diveSpotTypeID: req.body.diveSpotTypeID,
    diveSpotDescription: req.body.diveSpotDescription,
    diveSpotPhotos: req.body.diveSpotPhotos
})
    .then((diveSpot) => {

       console.log(diveSpot)

        res.status(200).json({
            statusCode: 200,
            success: true,
            message: "Success",
            diveSpot: diveSpot,
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
    });
};
```

Comment: Cheers, that is the posting fixed but the photos part is still returning null in Postgres. Do i need to reference the diveSpotPhotos part in my raw json? I only have it in the formData (key, value) parts.